# Best way to get a variables value

Tags: python

I have a bunch of variables

```
myvar1='say1'
myvar2='say2'
myvar3='say3'
myvar4='say4'
myvar4='say5'
```

To print them I use a for loop like

```
for i in (range 1,6):
  print('{}-{}'.format(i,vars()['myvar'+str(i)]))
```

and this produces

```
1-say1
2-say2
3-say3
4-say4
5-say5
```

My question is simply is this the best way to do this(I mean the var()[] part).  I tend to use this kind of thing a bit (not just for printing the variables value...) and I just think it looks funky.  I've been looking around for other examples and I really have not found any.  So, is there a better way?

So ultimately I am wondering what is the best way to get the value from a variable name in a variable?

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to achieve. It's certainly not **Pythonic**. Are you familiar with OOP and aware of Python's very extensive OO capabilities? What you're ding here (*assumptions*) is more suited to OO. (*Or simply a dictionary of key/value pair*).

Comment: You can do it but why not make a list or a tuple from myvars ?

Comment: This is very simplified but the general process is that I produce a variable name (and if it exists) pull the value from it.

Comment: Dump it in a tuple... Hmmm...

Comment: @pn1dude: Rephrase this in terms of a "User Requirement". What do you want the user to do, what should the program do in response to user input?

Comment: User would never see this...

Comment: Why are you cluttering your namespace with those? I can _prove_ it's a bad idea. You got 20% of the variable names wrong!

Comment: @gnibbler What?  This is an example not the real code.

Comment: @pn1dude You need to provide real code. As it stands this code is much better suited to just a simple list/tuple

Comment: I was not looking for an analysis of real code.  Agree that list/tuple will work better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`So, is there a better way`

Off-course, why not just use a list or if you need more estoric numbering, use a dictionary(or if order is important, use an OrderedDict`?

Example Code with list

```
>>> myvar = ['say1','say2','say3','say4','say5']
>>> for index, var in enumerate(myvar, 1):
    print "{}-{}".format(index ,var)


1-say1
2-say2
3-say3
4-say4
5-say5
```

Example Code using OrderedDict

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> myvar = OrderedDict(
            [('a','say'),
             ('b','say2'),
             ('c','say3'),
             ('d','say4'),
             ('e','say5')])
>>> for key, value in myvar.items():
    print "{}-{}".format(key,value)


a-say
b-say2
c-say3
d-say4
e-say5
```

Comment: You can avoid the `index + 1` by setting a start positing for `enumerate`. This is the second function parameter:

    `for index, var in enumerate(myvar,1):` and `print "{}-{}".format(index, var)`

Comment: @Jon: Yes thats true, you can use the start index of enumerate to avoid the + 1

Comment: This is a cool way of using OrderedDict...  But what I was looking for was the best way to execute a variable name in a variable.

Comment: @pn1dude That's what you provided. You asked for a better way, and this is one.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the OP's comments the best way to do this is with a Python `dict` (*Dictionary*) of key/value pairs.

**Example:**

```
data = {
    "1": "say1",
    "2": "say2",
    "3": "say3",
}
```

And then to get teh same output::

```
for k, v in data.items():
    print("{}-{}".format(k, v))
```

**Output:**

```
1-say1
2-say2
3-say3
```

Comment: I love the dictionary and use it a lot...  But what I was looking for was the best way to execute a variable name in a variable.

Comment: @pn1dude You're hung up on implementation details. You're asking the wrong question. You haven't considered that your implementation may just be bad design.

Comment: I sure have and that is why I asked...  Thanks for the response.